# laravel return redirect()->back()

Tags: laravel

Почему может не работать возврат return redirect()->back() на ту же страницу после совершения действия?

Дано: админ часть, я создаю объект и хочу, чтобы после его добавления (сохранения) меня не перекидывало в раздел, а оставляло на той же странице редактирования/добавления объекта.

В контроллере

```
public function store (Request $request) {

    $this->validatobject($request);

    $object = (new ObjectRepository())->createObject($request->all());
    if (!empty($object['error'])) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->all())
            ->withErrors(['error' => $object['error']]);
    } else {

        if($request->save_and_stay) {
            return redirect()->back()
            ->with('success', 'Объект успешно добавлен');
        }

        return redirect()
            ->route('admin.object.index')
            ->with('success', 'Объект успешно добавлен');
    }
}
```

Во вьюхе

```
<button type="submit" name="save_and_stay">Сохранить</button>
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать redirect()-> и оставить вот так
return back()
            ->withInput($request->all())
            ->withErrors(['error' => $object['error']]);

Comment: А вы уверены что у вас не сработало исключение до условия? Может в хандлере стоит обработка этих исключений, в том же валидаторе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вместо этого

```
if($request->save_and_stay)
```

нужно вот это

```
if(isset($_POST["save_and_stay"]))
```